# OAuth and authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

according to here (https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/) and many other things I have come across. OAuth is not meant to handle end user authentication. Reading through the article above and others while searching provides so much information at once from so many angles that it is hard to see through it all. ok...

**Does this mean that...**

**A)** The protocol itself is not intended to handle authentication, so therefore, OAuth client apps should inspect "who" can authorize users according to the OAuth providers?

If ONLY the user can authorize third party apps, then isn't the fact of receiving authorization from the OAuth provider in itself proof of authentication? (if this is the case, then can OAuth access tokens from places like Google and Facebook be trusted as authentications?)

**B)** OAuth client apps cannot trust authenticating users with OAuth, so therefore must provide another sound authentication mechanism alongside it?

If this is the case, then every site that I have clicked "Login With [provider]" (and no other complementary authentication scheme) has got authentication wrong?

It seems to me that if only trusted and specific OAuth providers are used, then this flow could infer authentication

1. App requests login with trusted providers
2. User is directed to provider to authorize (ONLY user can authorize)
3. App then requests and receives token from provider, and adds user to the app database if necessary.
4. Token is put into secure cookie or JWT and returned to the user to be presented on subsequent visits.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of OAuth2 access token is to delegate some access rights (scopes) from a user to a client application. So the application redirects the user to an authentication provider (OAuth2 server), which authenticates the user and asks the user (consent step) whether he/she wants to delegate some access rights (the scopes requested by the application) to the application.

If a client application receives an access token, it can get its meta data at the [OAuth2 introspection endpoint](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) - such as username of the user (resource owner). So this way, the OAuth2 can be used for authentication. But the main purpose of access tokens is to delegate some rights. For example if a third party application wants to save its data to a user's Google Drive, it needs an access token issued by Google with scopes that allow it to access Google Drive.

If you want to use OAuth2 only for authentication in your client application (to get identity of a user), you can use [OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) (OAuth2 extension) and its ID token, which is in JWT format and contains information about the user that was authenticated the authentication provider. This is better suited for the "Login With ..." functionality.

Comment: Nice answer, but from my understanding the token introspection should only be used by the protected resources (or resource server), not the client. Allowing clients to retrieve token details may lead to the leak sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks Florent for the comment. It's true the introspection RFC discusses just the protected resources that can call it. But I didn't find any restriction for other clients there. For example Google has its `/tokeninfo` public. Nonetheless, it's good to keep in mind that the introspection endpoint may be inaccessible for some clients, depending on the configuration.